# Сохранение положения скролла при возврате на страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery, браузер

Есть страница *А*. Мы опустились в самый низ и перешли по ссылке на страницу *В*.

Как сохранить положение окна (в данном случае самый низ страницы) по возврату на страницу *А*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На событии `$(window).unload(...)` сохранить позицию скролла страницы в локальном хранилище или куках. При возврате проверять наличие сохраненного значения и мотать до сохраненного значения.